# How can I get the prefix of the apostrophe using regex in Python3?

Tags: python, regex

[image]

I give a sample from the file. I wrote a regex in the picture. But I do not want the cut mark. I want Gemisi and Kayahan words. I used this regex but it didn`t work. How can I do this mission?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [*positive lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
[A-Z]\w+(?=')
```

this will *match* but *not consume* the quotation marks.

Comment: `pattern=r'[A-Z]\w+(?=')'` Tried now but it gave SyntaxError: invalid syntax for parentheses

Comment: @Serra: you should write you're **string** with double quotes, so `pattern=r"[A-Z]\w+(?=')"`. Because a single quote in a single quoted string of course does not work...